# Python : http request reduce upstream usage when using urlopen

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2, urllib

I am downloading a file repeatedly on many virtual machines on google cloud using the urlopen() function. The name of the file is https://resources.lendingclub.com/SecondaryMarketAllNotes.csv
The file is about 80MB, and what I am trying to do is minimize the amount of upstream data used when downloading the file. It seems to cost me around 80kb of upload to download the 80MB file. I am downloading it many times in a month (about 1.5 million times), so this 80kb of upload per transfer is turning into 120GB of data egress (upload) per month which is expensive for me. Any one aware of a method to download this file with less egress (upload) ?

Comment: Are the contents of the file changing often? Could you cache it and download it only if it has changed? If it hasn't changed, serve it from the cached copy.

Comment: The contents of file are changing frequently.

Comment: I would also suggest using compression by setting `Content-Encoding: gzip` but it seems that their server does not support it. Another possible option is to use their API - https://www.lendingclub.com/developers/lc-api.action

Comment: Can you please explain the caching approach? I will give it a try. I am loading the data in that file to memory using pandas and taking some action based on change in files content, ideally with less than a sub second latency.

Comment: You can read this: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching . There are plenty of other resources available, just search for them.